# What's the Difference between substring and substringData in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, substring

While Searching about substring, I found substringData. It seems they both quite similar but I don't understand why and when to use them.

Comment: substringData is part of the XMLDOM interface. I never heard of it before now and never had to use it, I guess it can be useful for a bit faster access to subportions of the text content of a node but if you are just learning you likely won't be interested in that. I'd suggest looking at things inside the String.prototype, such as substring, for your purpose (even in the use case of substringData you could just use textContent and then apply the regular substring method).

Answer (score 1):

From what I read, substring is a method defined for every string.

On the other hand substringData is only defined for nodes of the DOM.
But it will only work if the node has text in it.

If you have a DOM element (a node) as a variable and don't know if it has text in it, you can use its innerText and use substring on the innerText.
Example:

```
let start = length = 2;
let myNode = getRandomNodeFromDOM();   
let myString = myNode.innerText; // might be an empty string if no text
let mySubstring = myString.substring(start, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is method found on strings.

[`substringData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData/substringData) is a method found on [Node objects that contain characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData).

Which you use depends on the type of object you are working with in the first place (and you are very unlikely to be directly working with nodes in a ReactJS application).

Answer (score -1):

The **substringData()** method gets the string value from the comment, while the **substring()** method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub-string.

Answer (score -1):

**Difference between substring and substringData in javascript:**

1. str.substr() Function: The str.substr() function returns the specified number of characters from the given string at the specified index.

**Syntax:**

str.substr is an abbreviation for str.substr (start, len)

2. str.substring() This method get the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new string.

**Syntax:**

str.substring(start, end)

Comment: `substr` is not `substringData`